# How to clean up combined vars declarations in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

could anyone advice an option in Eclipse IDE for **cleaning up combined vars declarations**. I was unable to find one in "Clean up" settings for Eclipse.

To turn this:

`int a=0, b, c;`

into this:

```
int a=0;
int b;
int c;
```

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a setting or a plugin which would do *precisely* that kind of refactoring.

That would then be a good candidate for an **AST (Abstract Syntax tree) plugin**, like you can find in this **[JDT - AST Tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseJDT/article.html)**.